# Como saber quantas posições tem um array em Java?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Observem a imagem;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um upload de um arquivo CSV, e já estou conseguindo contar quantas linhas tem, no nosso contexto são três linhas como mostra no código abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu preciso agora e como conseguir pegar o número máximo de posições, eu não estou sabendo como pegar, eu sei que fazendo um debug consigo saber que o número máximo de posições é 10 como mostra na figura abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso saber como criar uma linha de código para pegar a quantidade de posições; esse é meu algoritmo;

```
    File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());
LineNumberReader linhaLeitura = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
linhaLeitura.skip(arquivoLeitura.length());
int qtdLinha = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;

BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getArquivo())));

String linha = null;

List<TotalIndicios> listaTotalDeIndicios = new ArrayList<TotalIndicios>();
List<IndiciosEntity> listaIndiciosEntity = new ArrayList<IndiciosEntity>();

for (int indiceDeIndicios = 1; indiceDeIndicios <= qtdLinha; indiceDeIndicios++) {

    linha = leitor.readLine();
    String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
    //vai fazer alguma coisa......
}
```

Comment: o que é o *" número máximo de posições"*? são seria só fazer o split dos valores da linha e pegar o count disso?

Comment: Eu encontrei o número de posições, encontrei esse 
códgo int numberPositions = dadosCSV.length
Se quiser você pode colocar isso como resposta e irei marca como certa.

Comment: sim era isso, a variável `dadosCSV` tem o array do conteúdo da linha obtido depois do `split`, o lenght mostra exatamente quantos itens tem no array :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linha no seu código que faz o *split*, já tem todos os elementos separados, então basta usar a propriedade `length` para obter a quantidade:

```
String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
Int quantidade = dadosCSV.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o metodo length te retorna quantas posiçoes há em um array.

```
dadosCSV.length
```